# How can solve that if we have two blue and we need three extractions?

Tags: probability

Three balls are extracted at random - without replacement - from a box with
one black, two blue and three white balls. What is the probability that all extracted balls are blue?

How can solve that if we have two blue and we need three extractions?

Comment: Of course you can solve it. The probability is simply $0$.

Comment: thank you! I suppose is equal with: $$\frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\cdot 0$$ I've right?